# How to open a command-line application with a command without closing it?

Tags: bash, command-line, startup, expect

I am trying to write a script that opens a command-line application (sagemath in this case) which on start up will send a certain command down the pipe (attach a script) without closing the application at the end.

I tried something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "load(\"script.sage\")" | sage
```

This, of course, opens sage load the script print the output of the script and closes sage. Adding & at the end of the last line didn't work.

I know that technically I can add this script to the list of scripts which are loaded on startup always but this is not what I want. I thought that it might be done be making a dynamic link at some directory to my script, but not sure if there is such a directory and where it is.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
I didn't know about Expect (I'm a youngster in linux). Reading about, following Mark's suggestion, it a bit I managed to solve this. If this is of any interest to anyone in the future then this does the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
spawn sage
expect "sage:"
send "load(\"script.sage\")\n"
interact
```

Comment: I am no expert on `expect`, but that should do it for you... http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/ You're going to need something like... `spawn sage`, `send "load script"`, `interact`. If you add `expect` to your tags, I guess @GlennJackman will tell you the answer later :-)

Comment: That really helped, thanks!!!

Comment: Mark, thanks for the love ;). @Guest111101111, you should add that as an answer, since it is correct.

Comment: Well done! Kudos for working it out for yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #!/usr/bin/expect
>
> set timeout 20
>
> spawn sage
>
> expect "sage:"
>
> send "load(\"script.sage\")\n"
>
> interact

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'screen' depending on how dynamically you need this script to run. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen for info on how to use screen.

Comment: Without details about how exactly to use `screen` to solve the OP's problem, this answer is rather useless.

Answer (score -1):

You can either:

Use nohup to start the program E.g., *nohup "load(\"script.sage\")" | sage*.

Or, you can use the disown command.